# Spring Data Jpa Problems

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Hello everybody first one excuse me for my bad english,
I am using spring framework and is configured with annotations but exist a error

this is my WebAppInitializer class i using for dispatcherServlet

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {RootConfig.class};
}

//Cofiguración especifica de clases
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.class};   
}

/**
 * Mapeo de DispatcherSerbvlet
 * @return 
 */
@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}
}
```

this Rootconfig class for scan the spring components

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.factory.soft.web"},
            excludeFilters = {
            @Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION,value=EnableWebMvc.class)})
public class RootConfig {}
```

And the last class WebConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc //Habilita SpringMVC

@ComponentScan("com.factory.soft")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
/**
 * El resolvedor de vistas de jsp
 * @return 
 */
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver(); 
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
    resolver.setViewClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}
@Bean
public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor paPostProcessor() {
    return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
}
/**
 * Configure Static contentc handling
 * @param configurer 
 */
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}}
```

for the JPA coniguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.factory.soft.repository")
public class JPAConfig {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db");
    dataSource.setUsername("user");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    return null;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emfb.setDataSource(dataSource());
    emfb.setPersistenceUnitName("SOFTPU");
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    emfb.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
    emfb.setPackagesToScan("com.factory.soft.domain");
    return emfb;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}

Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    return properties;
}

@Bean
public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
  HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
  adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
  adapter.setShowSql(true);
  adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
  return adapter;
}}
```

This is error track of netbeans

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'exceptionTranslation' defined in class path resource [com/factory/soft/data/JPAConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:220)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:618)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1540)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.aop.Advice
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
... 36 more
```

Comment: Could you post your `pom.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are in need of following Jar (`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.aop.Advice`):

`aopalliance-1.0.jar`

Please download the above Jar from `http://aopalliance.sourceforge.net/` and add to the `lib` folder of your web application. Alternatively you may add following dependency to your `pom.xml` if you are using `maven`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
    <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues,

1.add AOP related dependencies in POM

2.You're returning `dataSource` as `null` in `JPAConfig` class

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db");
    dataSource.setUsername("user");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    return null;
}
```

change the return value to `dataSource`

Comment: Thanks i add the AOP and return datasource, but now appear other error       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\U\U\Documents\soft\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\com\factory\soft\data\JPAConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryLookupStrategy$Key

Comment: Please post your `pom.xml` ?